# More identities of the Ramanujan Double factorial type.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, factorial, gamma-function

Ramanujan discovered the following identity

$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left[\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^3=\left[\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac98\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac54\right)\Gamma\left(\frac78\right)}\right]^{2}$$

which contained the double factorials . Are there any further identities of this type ? or probably its generalization .

Comment: It's nothing more than the [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of an [elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), evaluated in a certain point. There are tons of them, generated in the same manner, though not necessarily by Ramanujan. Unrelated to elliptic integrals, but related to [double factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), we have the following result, due to [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) : $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\bigg[\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}\bigg]^2=\frac4\pi$$

Comment: Also, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}=\sqrt2$$

Comment: @BalarkaSen can you please write down the proof , for better understanding and grasping.

Comment: The identity is wrong! You need a square on the right side. Probably its a typo. See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2393810/72031

Comment: I have fixed the typo mentioned in last comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible class of such *squared-double factorial* sums just comes directly from the $_2F_1$ hypergeometric expansion of $K = K(k)$, i.e.,

$$\frac{2 K}{\pi} = {}_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;k^2\right) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left [ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right ]^2 k^{2n}\tag{1}$$

Applying respectively *Kummer's transform* and then *Clausen transform* gives a *cubed-double factorial class*

\begin{align*}\frac{4K^2}{\pi^2} & = {}_3F_2 \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1;(2kk')^2\right) \\ & = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left [ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right ]^3 (2kk')^{2n} \tag{2} \end{align*}

This is the key to *Ramanujan's identity*, and presumably this answers your question about *generalizations*. Another cubic class is

$$\sum_{n\geq0} \left [ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right ]^3\!\!\!(6n+1)(2kk')^{2n}=\frac{4K(k)^2}{\pi^2}+\frac{24K(k)}{\pi^2}\left[\frac{E(k)-k' K(k)}{(1-2k^2) } \right] \tag{3}$$

An interesting consequence is the identity

$$\frac{4}{\pi}=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{6n+1}{4^n} \left [ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right ]^3$$

---

*Proof of $(2)$* $:$ [*Kummer's transformation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_relation) gives us, in general

$$_{2}F_{1}(2a, 2b; a+b+1/2; x) = {}_{2}F_{1}(a, b; a+b+1/2; 4x(1-x))$$

So inserting $(a, b, x) = (1/4, 1/4, k^2)$ clearly gives

$$_2F_1(1/2, 1/2; 1; k^2) = {}_2F_1(1/4, 1/4; 1; 4k^2k'^2) \tag{+}$$

The trick now is to square the right hand side of $(+)$ and use [*Clausen transform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen%27s_formula) to note that

$$\left[_2F_1(1/4, 1/4;1;4k^2k'^2)\right]^2 = {}_3F_2(1/2,1/2,1/2;1,1;4k^2k'^2)$$

Giving the equality at last, and thus proving $(2) \;\;\; \blacksquare$

*Proof of $(3)$* $:$ Differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $k$ gives

$$\frac{4(1-2k^2)}{k'}\sum_{n \geq 0} (2kk')^{2n-1} \cdot n \cdot \left [ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right ]^3 = \frac{8KK'}{\pi^2}$$

Where $K' = \frac{d}{dk}K(k)$. The above is clearly equivalent to

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} (2kk')^{2n} \cdot n \cdot \left [ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right ]^3 = \frac{4KK'}{\pi^2}\frac{kk'^2}{1-2k^2}$$

Multiplying the above with $6$ and adding to $(2)$ alongside with the $K$-differentiation formula

$$K'(k) = \frac{E(k) - k'^2K(k)}{kk'^2}$$

Gives the desired equality of $(3)\;\;\;\blacksquare$

Comment: Ramanujan describes a general procedure for such identities in his paper *Modular Equations and Approximations to $\pi$*. See [this post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html) for more details.